# How to find the names of the installed drivers in my computer in C?

Tags: c, winapi, drivers

I am trying to write a code that can get the names of the installed drivers in my Windows computer in C (via winapi)?

I am really new to C and I do not know what I can do ? Can you please help me with this situation ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the setup API. Start with this article: [How to enumerate hardware devices by using SetupDi calls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695)

Comment: Actually I have used this code before but I dont get the list of the installed drivers

Comment: What do you mean by "installed drivers"?

Comment: For example, I have plugged-in a device to my computer, and I want to check if that device's driver was installed before or not. Actually I used the code 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682619(v=vs.85).aspx

In here to get all devices but I have just a name for the device. I dont know how to compare with the file name now