# Winapi: How to check if driver is preinstalled on system?

Tags: c, winapi, driver, inf

I'm working with drivers and recently I ran to this problem. Before performing some operations, our software checks if specific driver is preinstalled using this function

```
  SetupCopyOEMInf(sourceInf, NULL, SPOST_NONE,
                  SP_COPY_REPLACEONLY | SP_COPY_NOOVERWRITE,
                      NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

It was copying the inf and if we got `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` error, we assumed that driver was preinstalled.

For some reason this function doesn't work on recent windows 10, Even if inf file already exist in `Windows/inf`, it returns true every time.

I'm curious if there is some other way of checking if driver is preinstalled using winapi? Thanks.

**P.S**

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538050/how-to-find-the-names-of-the-installed-drivers-in-my-computer-in-c) question and it didn't help me because, I don't have a device to plug in, my driver creates virtual network adapters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the names of the installed drivers in my computer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538050/how-to-find-the-names-of-the-installed-drivers-in-my-computer-in-c)

Comment: How could it be duplicate of that, if they are trying to enumerete the hardware devices, while my question is about if the driver is preinstalled?

Comment: Seems you don't read comments at all. There was useful comment about winapi [EnumDeviceDrivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682619(v=vs.85).aspx). Method is - enumerate all drivers and find yours in the list.

Comment: It gives the list of drivers, but my driver is not in the list. I've checked and my driver is in `System32/drivers` directory, what  conditions need to be met to have my driver in the list? It only appears there if I create device associated with the driver.

Comment: Hm..., seems that this api enumerates *loaded* drivers in memory - for active devices. Yes, you need something different - to get driver if device was active at some point in the past. Probably [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144063/check-if-a-windows-driver-exists-for-a-given-device-id) will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not the point. How can I check if driver is preinstalled on clean windows? In clean windows I mean OS which had never had my software (and of course my driver) installed before?

Comment: How about checking the registry under the services key? Not sure how reliable it is, but I recall drivers are typically registered there...

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: `I'm curious if there is some other way of checking if driver is preinstalled using winapi?` why do you think its `XY Problem`? @kvr which registry keys cointain such information?

Comment: @Ojs Check HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services and check each subkey, and look at the ImagePath, and Type values etc.